# How to write a Haskell Pipes "sum" function?

Tags: haskell, pipe

I'm trying to learn the `pipes` package by writing my own `sum` function and I'm getting stumped. I'd like to not use the utility functions from `Pipes.Prelude` (since it has `sum` and `fold` and other functions which make it trivial)  and only use the information as described in `Pipes.Tutorial`. The tutorial doesn't talk about the constructors of `Proxy`, but if I look in the source of `sum` and `fold` it uses those constructors and I wonder whether it is possible to write my `sum` function without knowledge of these low level details.

I'm having trouble coming to terms with how this function would be able to continue taking in values as long as there are values available, and then somehow return that sum to the user. I guess the type would be:

```
sum' :: Monad m => Consumer Int m Int
```

It appears to me this could work because this function could consume values until there are no more, then return the final sum. I would use it like this:

```
mysum <- runEffect $ inputs >-> sum'
```

However, the function in `Pipes.Prelude` has the following signature instead:

```
sum :: (Monad m, Num a) => Producer a m () -> m a
```

So I guess this is my first hurdle. Why does the `sum` function take a `Producer` as an argument as opposed to using `>->` to connect?

---

FYI I ended up with the following after the answer from danidiaz:

```
sum' = go 0
  where
    go n p = next p >>= \x -> case x of
      Left _        -> return n
      Right (_, p') -> go (n + 1) p'
```

Comment: well the `sum` in pipes takes something that *produces*  numbers and sums them up in a monadic action ... the idea is quite similar to yours if you think about it - also the package is designed so that you should not care about the details but use `fold` and the rest of the provided primitives ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Consumers` are actually quite limited in what they can do. They can't detect end-of-input ([pipes-parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-parse) uses a different technique for that) and when some other part of the pipeline stops (for example the `Producer` upstream) *that* part is the one that must provide the result value for the pipeline. So putting the sum in the return value of the `Consumer` won't work in general.

Some alternatives are:

- Implement a function that deals directly with `Producer` internals, or perhaps uses an auxiliary function like [`next`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl). There are adapters of this type that can feed `Producer` data to "smarter" consumers, like `Fold`s from the [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) package.
- Keep using a `Consumer`, but instead of putting the sum in the return value of the `Consumer`, use a `WriterT` as the base monad with a `Sum Int` monoid as accumulator. That way, even if the `Producer` stop first, you can still run the writer to get to the accumulator This solution is likely to be less efficient, though.

Example code for the `WriterT` approach:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Pipes

producer :: Monad m => Producer Int m ()
producer = mapM_ yield [1..10]

summator :: Monad n => Consumer Int (WriterT (Sum Int) n) ()
summator = forever $ await >>= lift . tell .  Sum

main :: IO ()
main = do
   Sum r <- execWriterT . runEffect $ producer >-> summator
   print r
```

Comment: "Can't detect end-of-input" was what I was missing. Thanks very much.